# Creating Bokeh effect

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Bokeh effect in image using Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449723/how-to-create-bokeh-effect-in-image-using-matlab)

I want to create Bokeh effect to images using matlab.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh

How can I accomplish it using Matlab?

Comment: It seems like a similar question to this one: [How to create Bokeh effect in image using Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449723/how-to-create-bokeh-effect-in-image-using-matlab) - there is a bit of code in the Question, but no answer.

Comment: @Birgit_B I saw that quastion, but this code didn't deliver the goods.

Comment: Mh, i did't find any useful code-exaples. I seems, you've got to go the hard way. Maybe this article can help you further? [Circularly symmetric convolution and lens blur](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=1495)

Comment: ... I have found an additional website, which might help you: [Java Image Processing - Blurring for Beginners](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html) has a lot of good exaples with web-applications to test them and the source code for each of the examples (but only in Java).

Comment: Slightly OT: are there objective improvements created by this effect?  This comes to mind b/c looking at bokeh on one screen pained my eyes, while it seemed pleasant on another.  Torturing a viewer or developer seems like a risk here.  Still, it is an interestting Q and I'd like to know more.

Comment: The question that this one supposedly duplicates is confounded and incomplete. Its title is nearly irrelevant. It asks for help removing undesirable artifacts, without providing the reference image. It has no answers, only one comment stating the obvious. That one should be closed, and this one should stand.

Answer (score 2):

As I undeerstand it there are two problems here:
1- To select the subject, or create a mask to separate subject from background.
2- To apply proper blurring to the background.

1- is a hard problem and depending on your use case you might want to approach it in many different ways.
2- for blurring you have many options in the MATLAB image processing toolbox I imaging a mixture of motion blur and gaussian blur would be a good starting place.

EDIT:
for #1 It all depends on the use case, you may be able to get away by defining a gradually decreasing (like a 2D Gaussian) mask centered on the center of the photo (assuming that "subjects" would be around the center most of the time) and do your blur on all the image them mix the original and the blurred version using the mask.

Comment: As Wikipedia article says, Bokeh effect is not blurring. You need to know the distance of the object from the lens to do it properly. "Unlike conventional convolution, this convolution has a kernel that depends on the distance of each image point"

Comment: @Andrey, if the object is sufficiently far enough in the background you can successfully produce the desired effect with constant blurring. It may not be exact but it often doesn't have to be.

Comment: I don't think motion blur would be appropriate.

Comment: Would #1 be helped by edge detection?

Comment: @Iterator certainly in some cases.

Comment: Btw, the wikipedia entry gives some general algo suggestions.  Some may have Matlab implementations already.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited number of things which you can do to replicate the Bokeh affect. In reality, Bokeh depends on the distance from the sensor to the target, the lens, etc. As an image is 2-d, then one would need to know the range to each pixel somehow in order to make this work. One can create some related effects without knowing the range, but this would be quite difficult to do from just the image. The subject of this would be a great P.H.D. dissertation, you might try asking on [Signals SE site.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

If you have a scene in 3-d, and you want to take an image in 2-d like a photograph, you could look into ray tracing programs. If this is what you want, I could gladly help you figure it out. But there again, you might be better off asking for it at the [Signals SE site.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)